# Identify inner tags in a web page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a website in which I should be able to identify components by hovering on it.
For example- if we are hovering over an image it should be identified as an image in a tooltip. If we are hovering over a div that has an image and text, then it should be identified as Image text component etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show text tooltip and image tooltip and both text and image tooltip.

you can change the content easily by jQuery tooltip UI.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#image").tooltip({ content: '<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/883/883371.png" />' }); 
   $("#text").tooltip({ content: 'simple text' }); 
    
   $("#imageandtext").tooltip({ content: '<span>simple text</span><br/><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/883/883371.png" />' }); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
    <a id="text" href="#" title="" >show text</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <a id="image" href="#" title="" >show image</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <a id="imageandtext" href="#" title="" >show image and text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The two examples you listed are different - one only shows the element you're hovering over, whereas the other one shows its child elements.

Regardless, the `element.tagName` method ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)) should be handy for you.

Also, if you have an `img` inside a `div`, and you hover over the `img`, you can display both elements' information by using the `target` and `currentTarget` properties of the event object you get in the mouseover event.  [Info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)

I believe you have to attach an event listener to every element you want this to fire on, not just the overall parent element - so you'll have to select all elements you're interested in, and loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.checkOnHover').hover(function() {
    var elem = $(this).html();//inner elements of div
    
  } //Handler when mouse entered
});
```

```html
<div class="checkOnHover">
  <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
</div>
```